# Why is wordpress forcing https link generation?

Tags: menus, links, https

I just moved a local site on my staging area, and I noticed that wp_nav_menu now automatically generates https links. Why? How can I disable it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: on a mamp environment with ssl activated, on installation wordpress setted the database url options with https in front. Just changed theme to http on the remote server. On the local mamp enviroment I had also to restart the server without ssl.